# What does it mean by a "multicultural classroom" in ESL context?

Tags: teaching

What does it mean by a "multicultural classroom" in the ESL context?

Is it a classroom comprised of students from different cultures?

Is it a class that is taught a syllabus that includes resources from various cultures?

I need authentic references.

Answer (score 1):

> A multicultural classroom is one in which both the students and the teacher are accepting of all races, cultures, and religions. This acceptance is evidenced by the books that are read, the activities that are completed, and the lessons that are taught.

For more info look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicultural_education).

Comment: The source is not authentic.

Comment: @user366312 I have updated the reference source.